# django-paypal ExpressCheckout second step?

Tags: django, django-paypal

i've been implementing [django-paypal](http://github.com/abi/django-paypal) but when it return token and payerID where can i handle this? i put the confirm.html template but it doesn't show anything...

By the way, im **Using PayPal Payments Pro**

any idea ???

Comment: Quick tip: look at the Network diagram for the fork of django-paypal you're using. It's waaaay behind the latest development/features and might be worth upgrading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you mean, handle them? [django-paypa](https://github.com/johnboxall/django-paypal)l handles the `token` and `payerId` itself for you.

Check out the example views.py code I posted at [how to deal with returnurl in django-paypal for paypal WPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128543/how-to-deal-with-returnurl-in-django-paypal-for-paypal-wpp). If that doesn't help, clarify the question and I'll give it a go!